# Is a coslice (slice under) category a full subcategory of it ambient category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, modules

Let $\operatorname{C}$ be a category and $c\in \operatorname{C}$ an object. Consider the coslice (sometimes called slice under) category ${\operatorname c}/{\operatorname C}$. My question is whether ${\operatorname c}/{\operatorname C}$ is in general a *full* subcategory of $\operatorname{C}$?
I am particularly interested in the case of commutative $\operatorname{R}$-algebras as the slice category ${\operatorname R}/{\operatorname{CRing}}$, and thus whether the category $\operatorname{R-Alg}$ of commutative $\operatorname R$-algebras is a full sub category of $\operatorname{CRing}$, the category of commutative rings.

Comment: I think this a reasonable question, though amenable to answering by simple examples as shown by Spencer below. As such it's borderline for MO. However, I would have phrased it as: is the forgetful functor $c/C \to C$ full? In particular, a ring may (in principle) have more than one algebra structure, and so you don't have a subcategory. Here's a more interesting question: _when_ is $c/C\to C$ full?

Comment: To me, this clearly belongs at MSE.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your comments and answers. Since I am quite new here, I was not really aware of the difference between MSE and MO. Now I am aware and yes this is certainly a MSE question.

Comment: Calling a category $\operatorname{CRing}$ `$\operatorname{CRing}$` is a good idea, but calling a category $\operatorname C$ `$\operatorname C$` (rather than just $C$ `$C$`) probably isn't.  Also, use *MathJax* `*MathJax*` rather than $\textit{math-mode fakery}$ `$\textit{math-mode fakery}$` for italics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a counterexample, consider $R = \mathbb{C}$. The automorphism $i \colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ given by complex conjugation is certainly a ring homomorphism, but it isn't $\mathbb{C}$-linear.

Edit: Another example would be the slice $p / \text{Set}$, where $p$ is a one element set. This category is the category of pointed sets, and not all maps between two sets will preserve the chosen point.